# Do I have to discard leftover sushi?

Tags: food-safety, sushi

We had a party Monday night and ordered Sushi for 20 people - about 25 percent of the Sushi went uneaten, mostly plain rolls like tuna and yellow tail.  I would hate to throw out 10+ rolls - any suggestions?

Comment: I was unaware that it was possible to have leftover sushi. Reminds me of a question I saw elsewhere once, on what to do with leftover champagne.

Comment: I had the same problem last month... I was so sad while throwing away all that yummyness...

Comment: A friend of mine lived in rural Japan for some time.  He said that whenever a Japanese family would host a dinner party, they would often order a 200+ piece sushi platter and there would always be leftovers.  He said that the common practice was to leave the leftover sushi on the kitchen counter overnight---unrefrigerated---and eat it the next morning for breakfast.  I'm not recommending you do that, but at least that's what a portion of the Japanese do!

Comment: I realize this is quite an old post, but I think this needs to be stated based on the  posters suggesting to "use your nose": While it is true that fresh fish should have no "fishy" or "off" odors, your nose is NOT a food safety indicator.  Plenty of food, sushi included, can smell fine and be simultaneously incubating bacteria that can make you sick.  Smell is NOT a reliable indicator of food safety!  That is why we have to recommend the consideration of time and temperature.

Answer (score 16):

I'm assuming these rolls contain *raw* fish. If that's the case I'd urge you not to eat them raw the following day. It might be safest to just throw it out, but you could try deep frying them in a light tempura batter. Just a few minutes should be enough to cook the fish.

Comment: mmm this sounds delicious.

Answer (score 5):

As hobodave points out, you'll need to cook the fish, because the leftovers won't be safe to eat raw.  While deep frying sounds tasty, I'd be concerned that the cooking time would be too short to kill much bacteria.  Perhaps you could layer them in a casserole dish, maybe throw some more rice, sesame seeds, sauce(s) on top, and bake until browned as an asian casserole of sorts.

Be smart, though, and if they've been out of the fridge for a long time, or if they smell strongly, just toss 'em.

Answer (score 4):

First a red flag on the raw fish here. That said, some shops keep the sushi refrigerated for a couple of days before selling it. It's not what I prefer, but it is still edible. If you kept it out on a buffet for a couple of hours then I'd say you're going to have to say goodbye to the rolls.

If you're willing to take them apart you could go for a stir fry solution. Let's say a fishy variation on [this recipe](http://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/stir-fried-sushi-rice-with-morels-ham-and-asparagus).

Before proceeding, consider carefully where the rolls have been and use your nose.

Answer (score 0):

chop up your left over raw fish into tiny pieces and mix well with finely sliced green spring onion, tiny bit of soy sauce and sesame oil. Top your rice with it and enjoy!

Comment: This is dangerously bad advice. Are you familiar with basic safe food handling practices?

Comment: Using refrigerated leftover raw fish for the next day has never been an issue for me. You have to be sure of the quality of your fish when you buy it though.

Comment: So... no, then?